# Как добавить картинку в выпадающие меню во VueJS

Tags: javascript, html, html5, vue.js, frontend

Проблема такая, имеется выпадающий список с названиями стран. Требуется добавить иконку с флагом каждой страны слева от названия. Все картинки в формате `.svg` соответственно. Вот так выглядит код, который рендерит список со странами:

```
           <select v-model="defCountry">
            <option
              v-for="item in countries"
              :selected="item.def"
              :key="item.key"
              :value="{key: item.key, val: item.val, def: item.def}"
            >
              {{item.val}}
            </option>
          </select>
```

То есть, у Австралии `key` `AU`, следовательно картинка должна быть `AU.svg`.

Вот таким образом я получаю названия стран:

```
this.countries = Object.entries(countriesList).map(([key, {name}]) => (
  {'key': key, 'val': name, 'def': false} 
))
```

Проблема заключается в том, что `option` не поддерживает `img` и я не могу просто напрямую добавить. Также я пробовал добавлять в объект поле, в котором бы был этот тэг, а потом рендерить его в HTML, но это не сработало. Много ещё чего перепробовал, но никак.

```
'img': `<img :src="" width="15" height="15" alt="">`
```

Всем заранее спасибо за ответы.

Comment: Проблема заключается в том, что `option` не поддерживает `img` - верно. Поэтому, убираешь `select` c `option` и верстаешь то же самое кастомным компонентом (через `ul` с `li`: элементы `li` могут содержать `img`).

Answer (score 2):

Стандартный `select` вместе со всеми `option`'ами рендерится стилями браузера/ОС.

То, что вы хотите реализовать (и *так*, как вы хотите это реализовать) невозможно (ладно, может сейчас есть какие-нибудь CSS-хаки, которые бы позволили изменять стандартный вид `select`'ов, но я о таких не знаю и использовать крайней не рекомендую).

Либо делайте велосипед, реализующий функционал `select`'а, либо используйте готовые решения, коих как минимум сотни. Фраза для поиска - "vue custom select".

Answer (score 0):

```
option:after {
    content: " ";
    height: 15px;
    width: 15px;
    background-img: url();
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: также можна юзать :before, удачики

Comment: Без шансов, ничего из этого не работает. Впрочем неважно, я уже решил это